# Facebook sdk on iOS shows profile pic in simulator but not device

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I have the Facebook sdk getting profile pics in my iPhone simulator.  But for some reason it doesn't get the image on the device.  I'm using the FBProfilePictureView.

```
/** The user's profile picture. */
@property (nonatomic, strong)       IBOutlet    FBProfilePictureView    *profilePic;
```

And setting the user id

```
[cell.profilePic setProfileID: user.fbid];
```

Has anyone else come across this?

I can get mine back the same way.  But I can't get friends'

Answer (score 0):

You can try my replacement profile picture view which provides better error reporting through the added `completionHandler` property on the view... https://github.com/combinatorial/DBFBProfilePictureView

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem as well.And solved it. For me, I just copy the Profile Picture View from the facebook demo project. If you did this as well. Do the following to solve it

1. Drag a UIView into your storyboard from collection
2. Set the class of that View as FBProfileView
3. Connect it with your code

If still not working, check did you pre-load that class.
Add the `[FBProfilePictureView class];` as the first line in the app delegate method of didFinishLaunching

Wish to help you